# MVC4 bundling of DevExpress controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

Is it possible to use MVC4's bundling and minimization on DevExpress' web controls?  They have css declared like so:

```
<% Html.DevExpress().RenderStyleSheets(Page,
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
        new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report }
 ); %>

<% Html.DevExpress().RenderScripts(Page,
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report }
); %>
```

Can this be wrapped into the new Web.Optimization bundling and minimizer?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the answer is no. the DevExpress scripts use some variable names that may be used in other files, for example they may have a variable called currentGrid, which you may have as well. when the DevExpress scripts run, they check any previously defined variables for conflicts, and update to make their own usage unique. I haven't seen any answer where we can bundle these, though I would like the option as well.